# Differentiate two Angular components created by the same parent

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal component that only shows a message and an `accept button`.

The `accept button` will perform a function depending on who has called you.

The same component could create several modals (showed in diferent moments).

The problem I have is that to open the modal I have to call it by its id, but all modals are created with the same id. I had thought of creating a unique id for each one by passing it through the `@Input decorator`, but because it is a large application, two developers may call it in the same way and create conflicts.

How could I create a unique id for each element without having to pass it on as `@Input`?

I try to do an exemple, but have problems with jquery.

In any case here is the attempt

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gvqdzc

Comment: why is the modal responsible for the action ?

Comment: It's not responsible for the action... only emmit the response and the parent do the action... but I need to know wich of the modal emitt it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand completely you problem, but you can pass data to the dialog (in this case an id). Something like this,

*parent.component.ts*

```
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogChacraFormComponent, {
      width: 500,
      maxHeight: 500,
      id: idx
});
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(id => {
      doSomething(id);
});
```

*dialog.component.ts*

```
constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogChacraFormComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public id: number
) { }
onAccept() {
    this.dialogRef.close(this.id);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I want to have a component like this 
`<confirmation-modal [header]="'ARE_YOU_SURE'" [message]="'SENDED_MESSAGE'"
  (launchAction)="modal1Accepted()">
</confirmation-modal>`
Maybe yours works, but I look less elegant and maybe the doSomething() is tigger when close even if its not accepted. I try to do a stackblitz... I attach in the main ask.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution although it seems some confusing.

In the directive I add an ngif so that it is available only if a certain value.

```
<confirmation-modal *ngIf="expression == 'roles'" [header]="'ARE_YOU_SURE'" [message]="'SENDED_MESSAGE'" (launchAction)="modal1Accepted()">
```

And then in the modal opening function, I have to put the opening function in a setTimeout() because otherwise it cannot be found.

```
openRolesModal() {
this.expression = 'roles';
let modal = '#selectAttributtesModal';
setTimeout(() => $(modal).modal('show'), 100);
}
```